# How to persist value in select on automatic page reload

Tags: javascript

I have JS code that stores a value in a select on page reload. This code works well, but it is attached to the submit button.

**My code:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var item = localStorage.getItem('test');
  var select = document.getElementById("test");
  select.value = item;
});

function submitForm() {
  var select = document.getElementById("test");
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage.setItem('test', value);
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm()">
  <select class="form-select" name="test" id="test">
    <option>Select value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How do I change this code so that it also persists the value across reload when it happens automatically when the value changes by pasting this code into the form:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

I would like the page to reload automatically and still keep the value in the select.

Comment: use session storage if you just want to use javascript or you have to use some backend for this

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `beforeunload` event listener instead of your submit function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

```
document.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("test");
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage.setItem('test', value);
});
```